# Naming conflict between field values and local scope in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, naming-conventions

This is a coding style question rather then a technical one.

I have frequently encountered a problem where I use haskell's (less then optimal) record syntax (or lenses, the problem ends up the same) to create a `data` type.  I end up with field accessor functions named after my fields.  Being a conscientious programmer, I try to make my record field names meaningful.

At some point later I need to get a field out of my type and keep its value in a local variable.  This is often done within a StateMonad in a `do` block.  The question is what do I call the local variable.  The most obvious name is already taken as the field accessor.  I find my self using abbreviations which tends to make my code less readable.

Is there a Haskell coding convention that addresses this issue?

**Example**

```
data Qaax = Qaax {
      foo :: SomeFoo
    , bar :: SomeBar
    , ...
    }

baz :: (MonadState Qaax m) => (...) -> m ()
baz (...) = do
  f <- gets foo -- I'd really like to use something more descriptive then
                -- `f` but `foo` is already taken.
  ...
  return ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding ' as a suffix is an established convention for forming distinct-but-related names. A key example is `foldl` and `foldl'`.

In exported names like `foldl'` it's usually a good idea to come up with a consistent theme for what the ' means for your library (often it's "stricter version of", as in `foldl'`). But in local names you can be a lot freer to just use it "another closely related thing I would like to have the same name as".

The downside is that it's not *very* distinct, so it can hurt readability; especially if you need to commonly refer to both versions. And when you find yourself needing `foo'''` you should probably think about a different naming scheme!

Answer (score 4):

The [`NamedFieldPuns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) extension can help with this. When pattern-matching on a record, it binds a variable with the same name as a record field:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

baz :: (MonadState Qaax m) => m ()
baz = do
  Qaax {foo} <- get
  return ()
```

One possible problem is that the accessor is shadowed for the rest of the `do` block.